# How to securely load data to a database in vendor server such that vendor does not see raw data at all?

Tags: privacy, databases, file-upload

**Scenario**: client will be uploading files with sensitive information to a vendor server for loading into a database. Due to the confidential nature of the files, the client does not want any archiving of the raw files in the vendor server. In fact, **the client wants a solution wherein the vendor will not be able to see the raw files at all**.

A proposed solution is for the client to encrypt the files and then a program on the vendor server side to handle:

- decryption,
- trigger of database upload, and then
- deletion of the files.

Would you know of any technologies/techniques that would elegantly address this problem?

Comment: Is the file saved as a blob or is the DB going to parse the file and store in tables?

Comment: Hi Joe, I believe some parsing will be done before the data is loaded into the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no point in sending up the files encrypted to then have the vendor decrypt and process them. If you don't want the vendor to access them then the only options are to not send them up in the first place or send them up encrypted without giving the vendors the keys.

If the vendor can decrypt the files then, by definition, they have full access to the files, and there is no way you can also *not* give them the files. Your goals are mutually contradictory.  Either send the vendor the files and trust them to abide by the terms of your business agreement, or send the files encrypted and don't give them the keys. There is literally no middle ground here.

Comment: Thanks Conor! I'm on the same line of reasoning, exactly.